# Foxit PhantomPDF: Search for next comment?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, comments, foxit-reader

Does a method exist in Foxit Reader which allows the user to search forward or backward to the next page which has comments posted?

I'm referring to the yellow popup bubbles.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend opening the comments pane by clicking on the "speech bubble" icon on the left side of the window. Then, if comments are not already sorted by page, click on the "sort" icon within the pane (arrows pointing up and down) and sort by Page.

Comment: This does not exist for the regular Foxit Reader, correct?  I am unable to find any method of listing all comments, or searching through them.  The only method appears to be scanning the document by eye, which is very inefficient and error-prone.

Comment: Yes, it does. [This](http://imgur.com/4Ohh1uW) is how it looks in the latest Reader. If you don't see the buttons on the left, go to View > Navigation Panels > Reset All Panels.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to apply to Foxit for OSX, which is what I'm running.  There is no "comments" button on the left pane, and the menu View > Navigation Panels does not have an option to "Reset All Panels".  I checked for updates but I was up to date.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was talking about the Windows version. The OSX version does not have the comments panel yet.